# Spring data neo4j SDN 6

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In SDN 6, @Deapth annotation is removed, and also in the latest 6.0.3, support for bi-directional relationship is added. Earlier it was giving StackOverflow while persisting a 2-way relation between the same node entities. For eg A-follows->B and B-follows->A.
Now, this type of relationship is possible but when you load the Node with find* methods, it gets overly slow because of the nested relation, and also Depth is removed so it loads the entire relationship.
Do we have any workaround on this?

Comment: Apparently, I cannot add comments so writing it here. I've decided to downgrade to 5.3.6 for now which is solving my purpose. But definitely looking forward to a solution in SDN 6. I observed SDN 6 was muchr to work with. I'm very happy that the SDN team is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact same issue. Apparently, there is no workaround that I've found so far. The query keeps running and eventually fails with Outofmemory error.

The issue happens because of the self reference. This appears to be a defect since the self-reference nodes appear to be the ideal use case for graphs whereas they break while trying to find the nodes. Here is my query that is generated by SDN:

```
MATCH (n:Part) WHERE n.sku = "SKU000009"  WITH n, id(n) AS __internalNeo4jId__ RETURN n{.allowCustomerReviews, __nodeLabels__: labels(n), __internalNeo4jId__: id(n), __paths__: [p = (n)-[:SOLD_BY|GROUPED_WITH|PART_OF|FITS_INTO]->()-[:SOLD_BY|GROUPED_WITH|PART_OF|FITS_INTO|MANUFACTURED_BY*0..]-()-[:MANUFACTURED_BY*0..1]->()-[*0..]-() | p]}
```

Comment: do you intend to leave SDN and use low abstraction options like Neo4jTemplate? I am almost stuck on this.

Comment: We are currently investigating (and it looks promising) alternatives to the path based approach when it comes to self-references / cycles because "we hear you" but need time to evaluate the options and give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks @meistermeier for the update, Since I need to productionise the application in next one month and I guess this will not be changed in one month so my one question is if I don't use self-referencing/cycles in my graph model and use latest 6.0.3 SDN, than am I guaranteed to have optimized find queries? like earlier SDNs

Comment: If your Java model does not lead into those cycles that can open up the access to the whole graph, yes. I assume that there will be service release in the middle of February but we depend on the Spring Data team to release this. Just to be clear: Even with the update, SDN will still fetch the whole graph because this is what is defined in your Java model if this will get mapped. BUT it should not crash the database and as a consequence the application anymore.

Comment: So I tested with graph not creating cycle but my java model has relationships which are self-referencing, the only diff I did was not creating a 2-way relation and only having one-way relation still, the query produced by SDN is crashing the database.